# How to check if object is an jQuery Xhr object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I am in a situation where I would like to check if an object is a jQuery XHR (jqXHR -- such as is returned by .ajax() requests) -- not just a regular Deferred object.

I have tried checking if it's an instance of $.Deferred so it's slightly different:

```
xhrObj instanceOf $.Deferred       //false
```

And I don't see in the docs or code what constructor it is... Anyway to do this?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski but is xhrObj a deferred, isn't it a promise instead?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you want to know if it's a promise object, or if it is a jqXHR. a jqXHR is a promise object, however not all promise objects are jqXHR objects.

Comment: Edited -- I don't believe this is a duplicate because I want to know if it's a jqXHR not just a deferred

Comment: @EvanHobbs then you should check for `getAllResponseHeaders` method imho

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks. that was the conclusion I came to also, though with setRequestHeaders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check for any property that a deferred should have, such as `done`, `fail`, `always`, `state`,  etc.

`done` seems like something a deferred should have (which promises also have), that isn't very common among other jQuery objects.

```
var def = new $.Deferred();

if ('done' in def)
```

and to check if it's a promise

```
var ajax = $.ajax({
    url : 'something'
})

isPromise = 'abort' in ajax;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm using your approach though I want to know if it's jqXHR not just a regular $.Deferred (I think I wasn't clear in my question)... I decided to check for setRequestHeader since jqXHR has it but normal promises don't. I'm marking yours as correct though you might want to update the answer slightly.

Comment: @EvanHobbs - Yup, something like that should work, it also seems promises have "abort", which Deferreds doesn't ?

Comment: yes but the idea is to tell if it's a jqXHR not just a normal  Deferred. If it has 'done', 'fail', 'always', etc it's a Deferred but not necessarily a jqXHR which is a Deferred with additional properties. That's why I'm suggesting something like 'setRequestHeaders' which only jqXHRs have