# Abort an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My currentReq var is set to a call back method:

```
this.currentReq = cb.apply(this,args);
```

Later I may wish to abort the method if it is an ajax call.

I know I can use:

```
this.currentReq.abort();
```

But what if the currentReq is not an ajax call? How can I test for this and only abort if its an ajax call? I get an error when I try and abort on a standard deferred.

Comment: in general in these situations, you look for a "smoking gun" that only the one you need to target has or has set to a certain value.

Comment: Related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233035/how-to-check-if-object-is-an-jquery-xhr-object)

Comment: mmm... why not just do the classic duck typing thing and see if its abortable? Unless you have other abortable calls that aren't the ajax calls you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may first test to see if the `abort` method exists:

```
if (typeof(this.currentReq.abort) == "function") {
     this.currentReq.abort();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the error is to an undefined method the you should be able to test if the function itself exists

```
if(typeof this.currentReq.abort === 'function') {
    this.currentReq.abort();
}
```